# Remove directory from URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to remove a directory from my homepage link

example.com/remove/ to example.com

thing is, the index is located in the "remove" directory.

I've tried:
`RewriteRule ^front /(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

But this produced an internal server error

Comment: `DirectoryIndex remove/index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `httpd.conf` change this in `httpd.conf`

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/remove"
```

If you are running xampp or having a linux setup you will find httpd.conf in conf folder which is having below line in which you have to add your remove directory which will be your new root directory then every call to `example.com` will forwarded to `example.com/remove`.

And then restart your server.

Or if not use this in `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !remove/   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /remove/$1 [L]
```